# Task execution section of task definition for Id : .... is either missing or not valid

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an Azure Pipelines definition with two consecutive tasks

1. Run build
2. Manual approval step for QA work (depends on build)

In `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
jobs:
- job: Build
  ...
- job: QualityAssurance
  pool: server

  dependsOn: Build
  steps:
  - task: ManualIntervention@8
    inputs:
      instructions: Instructions for quality assurance and approval are here
```

When running the pipeline I get the following error:

```
Task execution section of task definition for Id : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx is either missing or not valid.
```

According to docs for [ManualInterventionV8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention) there are no required parameters.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Running into the same issue. @jsalonen, did you manage to find a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's not supported yet within build pipelines.

From https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/356708/cannot-use-manualintervention.html

> According to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention?view=vsts#demands , Manual Intervention Task now cannot support in build pipeline, please change other task to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Some years later, the [ManualValidation@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) is what works for me.